# Javascript behaviour while using parameter of method inside an object

Tags: javascript

I am fairly new to Javascript and stomped across this while writing some frontend code. I reproduced this here:

```js
var obj1 = {

  func1(val) {
    if (!this.obj2) {

      this.obj2 = {
        func2() {
          console.log(val);
        }
      }
    }
    this.obj2.func2();
  }
}
obj1.func1(10);
obj1.func1(20);
```

Why is the value of the `val` not getting changed inside the `func2()` method? It seems that only the value is getting copied to the object `obj2` without taking the reference into consideration.

But it works perfectly when I change the code to this:

```js
var obj1 = {

  func1(val) {
    this.val = val;
    var that = this;
    if (!this.obj2) {

      this.obj2 = {
        func2() {
          console.log(that.val)
        }
      }
    }
    this.obj2.func2();
  }
}
obj1.func1(10);
obj1.func1(20);
```

Can anyone tell the reason behind the difference? Is it something to do with the scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first snippet, when you do

```
if (!this.obj2) {
  this.obj2 = {
    func2() {
      console.log(val);
    }
  }
}
```

The `obj2` method that has been assigned, which gets assigned *once* and never again, *closes* over the `val` parameter in its scope when it was assigned - that is, when `obj1.func1(10)` was run.

In the second snippet, you assign to the `val` property of the instance every time `func1` runs:

```
func1(val) {
  this.val = val;
```

so by the time you log `that.val` later, it's always the parameter you just passed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. If I understand correctly, `func2` is a closure, right? And the second snippet works because `func2` closes over the `that` variable, but not over the `that.val`. So, it can still access the modified value through that object reference. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, in the first, the assigned function closes over the parameter passed to the method when the method is called for the first time. In the second, closures don't have anything to do with it - the difference is that the second has `this.val = val;`, changing the instance, so logging the property on the instance shows a change. If you changed the first snippet to `this.val = val;` on the first line, you'd also see the change logged.

Answer (score 1):

On the first case, you have:

```
    if (!this.obj2) {
      this.obj2 = {
        func2() {
          console.log(val);
        }
      }
    }
```

So you make func2 always console.log the value it was originally created with. The second time it's called it will just call func2 with original `val` because functions retain access to the original scope they were declared (this is called closure).

The second time, when you do

```
this.val = val;
var that = this;
```

You're going to console.log a dynamic reference to `this`, so it's going to be value you passed because the `this` is going to be different on this scop

Answer (score 0):

as far as I can understand the "This" keyword in javascript always points to the app itself or a global object. What you just did is setting a reference to the variable you are trying to use which is how I remedy this behaviour mistimes. I hope this helped at least?

have a look at this post. [understanding the this keyword](https://betterprogramming.pub/understanding-the-this-keyword-in-javascript-cb76d4c7c5e8)

cheers.